# How do I find the Conversion Action ID for use in the Google Ads API?

Tags: google-ads-api

I'm using the latest (v7) Google Ads API to upload offline conversions for Google Ads, using the Python Client Library. This is the standard code I'm using:

```
import os

from google.ads.googleads.client import GoogleAdsClient
client = GoogleAdsClient.load_from_env(version='v7')

def process_adwords_conversion(
    conversion_date_time, 
    gclid, 
    conversion_action_id, 
    conversion_value
):

    conversion_date_time = convert_datetime(conversion_date_time)

    customer_id = os.environ['GOOGLE_ADS_LOGIN_CUSTOMER_ID']
    click_conversion = client.get_type("ClickConversion")
    conversion_action_service = client.get_service("ConversionActionService")
    click_conversion.conversion_action = (
        conversion_action_service.conversion_action_path(
            customer_id, conversion_action_id
        )
    )
    click_conversion.gclid = gclid
    click_conversion.conversion_value = float(conversion_value)
    click_conversion.conversion_date_time = conversion_date_time
    click_conversion.currency_code = "USD"

    conversion_upload_service = client.get_service("ConversionUploadService")
    request = client.get_type("UploadClickConversionsRequest")
    request.customer_id = customer_id
    request.conversions = [click_conversion]
    request.partial_failure = True
    conversion_upload_response = (
        conversion_upload_service.upload_click_conversions(
            request=request,
        )
    )
    uploaded_click_conversion = conversion_upload_response.results[0]
    print(conversion_upload_response)
    print(
        f"Uploaded conversion that occurred at "
        f'"{uploaded_click_conversion.conversion_date_time}" from '
        f'Google Click ID "{uploaded_click_conversion.gclid}" '
        f'to "{uploaded_click_conversion.conversion_action}"'
    )

    return False
```

I believe the code is fine, but I'm having problems locating the conversion_action_id value to use. In the Google Ads UI there's a screen listing the different Conversion Actions, with no sign of an ID anywhere. You can click on the name and get more details, but still no ID:

[The conversion action detail screen in Google Ads UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gohgu.png)

I've tried the following:

1. Using the ocid, ctId, euid, __u, uscid, __c, subid URL parameters from this detail page as the conversion_action_id. That always gives an error:

```
partial_failure_error {
  code: 3
  message: "This customer does not have an import conversion action that matches the conversion action provided., at conversions[0].conversion_action"
  details {
    type_url: "type.googleapis.com/google.ads.googleads.v7.errors.GoogleAdsFailure"
    value: "\n\305\001\n\003\370\006\t\022dThis customer does not have an import conversion action that matches the conversion action provided.\0320*.customers/9603123598/conversionActions/6095821\"&\022\017\n\013conversions\030\000\022\023\n\021conversion_action"
  }
}
```

2. Using the standard Google answer:

https://support.google.com/google-ads/thread/1449693/where-can-we-find-google-ads-conversion-ids?hl=en

Google suggests creating a new Conversion Action and obtaining the ID in the process. Unfortunately their instructions don't correspond to the current UI version, at least for me. The sequence I follow is:

- Click the + icon on the Conversion Actions page
- Select "Import" as the kind of conversion I want
- Select "Other data sources or CRMs" then "Track conversions from clicks"
- Click "Create and Continue"

I then get the screen:

[Screen following Conversion Action creation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6z3hd.png)

The recommended answer says:

> The conversion action is now created and you are ready to set up the tag to add it to your website. You have three options and the recommended answer in this thread is discussing the Google Tag Manager option, which is the only option that uses the Conversion ID and Conversion Label. If you do not click on the Google Tag Manager option you will not be presented with the Conversion ID and Conversion Label.

Not so! What three options? The first "Learn more" link mentions the Google Tag Manager, but in the context of collecting the GCLID, which I already have. The "three options" mentioned in the official answer have gone. Clicking "done" simply takes me back to the Conversion Actions listing.

3. Using the REST API

I've tried authenticating and interrogating the endpoint:

https://googleads.googleapis.com/v7/customers/9603123598/conversionActions/

hoping that would give a list of conversion actions, but it doesn't. It just gives a 404.

Does anybody know a way of getting the Conversion Action ID, either from the UI or programmatically (via client library, REST or some other method)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you're using Python, you can list your conversions via next snippet:

```py
ads: GoogleAdsServiceClient = client.get_service('GoogleAdsService')
pages = ads.search(query="SELECT conversion_action.id, conversion_action.name FROM conversion_action", customer_id='YOUR_MCC_ID')
for page in pages:
    print(page.conversion_action)
```

You can also open conversion action in UI and locate `&ctId=`, that's the conversion action id.

Comment: When there is no date range in the query, how back in time does it go? How can I extend the time to get data?

Comment: Hey Elad, I think the query represents only what you have in your conversion settings. It's not the conversions itself, but just a config that you can set up on UI. So when you set up a new conversion, and want to get ID programmatically, this query will work. For deleted conversions, sadly I'm not sure if it'll work

Comment: Thanks, is there any API to get the same data as I would from the report? see: https://i.imgur.com/DBFo7so.png

Answer (score 2):

I found [this post](https://support.google.com/google-ads/thread/105330243/where-can-i-find-conversion-action-id-for-google-ads-api-upload-offline-conversion?hl=en&msgid=105402750) with the solution how to get the Conversion Action ID:

> (…) I found out that conversionActionId can be found also in Google
> Ads panel. When you go to conversion action details, in URL there is
> parameter "ctId=123456789" which represent conversion action id.

By the way, I tried [something similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631138/retract-conversion-from-google-ads-with-python) and it's still not working, but with this Conversion Action ID I get a different "Partial Failure" message, at least.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that iink. As it happened, I've already tried the ctId parameter (see 1 above). Whether I use this parameter or just put a random number, I always get the same message:  partial_failure_error { code: 3  message: "This customer does not have an import conversion action that matches the conversion action provided., at conversions[0].conversion_action"}

Comment: I obviously read over your paragraph numbered as 1, sorry for that. I am looking for help now on the official Google Ads API Forum, too, see https://groups.google.com/g/adwords-api/c/vg1XZgCF-aw . Did you solve your problem meanwhile?

Comment: Thanks for the help. No, I haven’t found a way round the problem. Between the multiple versions of the API and the poor documentation, this simple project has become a major headache.

Comment: No fix yet, but I've found out a bit more.

First, the Google Tag Manager option does appear, but ONLY if you select website conversions in the first step. 

Second, the post you linked to before saying that ctld parameter is the conversion ID is definitely wrong. I created a website conversion action and got the ID from Tag Manager. It doesn't correspond to the ctld value at all.

All of this hasn't helped - I still get the same partial error saying "This customer does not have an import conversion action that matches the conversion action provided."

Answer (score 1):

At least in Google Ads API (REST) v10,
it works if field conversionAction is set with value:
'customers/{customerId}/conversionActions/{ctId}'
customerId - without hyphens
ctId - conversion action id, as mentioned in above comments,
taken from GET parameters in Google Ads panel when specific conversion is opened.
Can also be found programmatically with API method.