# Upload Offline Conversion migration to V9

Tags: google-ads-api

I used to upload offline conversion using following code in v201809 version as provided at
https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib/blob/master/examples/AdWords/v201809/Remarketing/UploadOfflineConversions.php

```
$oAuth2Credential = (new OAuth2TokenBuilder())->fromFile()->build();
$session = (new AdWordsSessionBuilder())->fromFile()->withOAuth2Credential($oAuth2Credential)->withClientCustomerId($customerid)->enablePartialFailure()->build();

$adWordsServices = new AdWordsServices();
$offlineConversionService = $adWordsServices->get($session, OfflineConversionFeedService::class);
$conversionName="OfflineConv";
$feed = new OfflineConversionFeed();
$feed->setConversionName($conversionName);
$feed->setConversionTime($conversionTime);
$feed->setConversionValue($conversionValue);
$feed->setGoogleClickId($gclid);

$offlineConversionOperation = new OfflineConversionFeedOperation();
$offlineConversionOperation->setOperator(Operator::ADD);
$offlineConversionOperation->setOperand($feed);
$offlineConversionOperations = [$offlineConversionOperation];
$result = $offlineConversionService->mutate($offlineConversionOperations);
```

Now I am upgrading to V9, I have used the code as provided at
https://github.com/googleads/google-ads-php/blob/main/examples/Remarketing/UploadOfflineConversion.php

```
$oAuth2Credential = (new OAuth2TokenBuilder())->fromFile()->build();
$googleAdsClient = (new GoogleAdsClientBuilder())->fromFile()->withOAuth2Credential($oAuth2Credential)->build();

//$conversionName="OfflineConv";
$conversionName = ConversionActionType::WEBPAGE;
$clickConversion = new ClickConversion([
'conversion_action' => ResourceNames::forConversionAction($customerId, $conversionName),
'gclid' => $gclid,
'conversion_value' => $conversionValue,
'conversion_date_time' => $conversionTime,
'currency_code' => 'USD'
]);
$conversionUploadServiceClient = $googleAdsClient->getConversionUploadServiceClient();
$result = $conversionUploadServiceClient->uploadClickConversions($customerid, [$clickConversion], true);
```

The problem is when we set $conversionName="OfflineConv"; we get following error.
Resource name 'customers/9025381111/conversionActions/OfflineConv' is malformed: expected 'customers/{customer_id}/conversionActions/{ConversionType.conversion_type_id}'., at conversions[0].conversion_action

and when we set $conversionName = ConversionActionType::WEBPAGE; we get following error.
This customer does not have an import conversion action that matches the conversion action provided., at conversions[0].conversion_action

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Conversion Name must match the conversion action that you've already set up in your account. You're passing the enum value for the type.

It should be something like $conversionName = "OfflineConversions"
where "OfflineConversions" is exactly the name of the conversion in the conversions section of the web UI.

Comment: First of all thank you for your response, and yes I'm using exact conversion name as appear in web interface. It's working in v201809 but in V9 I get the error
Resource name 'customers/9025381111/conversionActions/OfflineConv' is malformed: expected 'customers/{customer_id}/conversionActions/{ConversionType.conversion_type_id}'., at conversions[0].conversion_action

Answer (score 0):

ConversionName has been removed from V9, use `$conversionActionId` as in example on github.

You need to try use parameter **ctId**  from url your "OfflineConversions" in Google Ads UI as `$conversionActionId`.

[Or try the solution from here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67689225/how-do-i-find-the-conversion-action-id-for-use-in-the-google-ads-api)

For your example, replace this

```
$conversionName = ConversionActionType::WEBPAGE;
```

on this

```
$conversionName = {ctId  from url};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to first create a click conversion

```
click_conversion = adwords_client.get_type("ClickConversion")
conversion_action_service = adwords_client.get_service('ConversionActionService')
    click_conversion.conversion_action = (
        conversion_action_service.conversion_action_path(
            customer_id, conversion_action_id
        )
    )
```

The conversion_action_id is equivalent to conversion_name of previous version.
You can find the id using following snippet

```
ads: GoogleAdsServiceClient = self.adwords_client.get_service('GoogleAdsService')
pages = ads.search(query="SELECT conversion_action.id, conversion_action.name FROM conversion_action where conversion_action.name={conversion_name}", customer_id={customer_id})
    for page in pages:
        print(page.conversion_action)
```

Then you upload the conversion

```
click_conversion.gclid = gclid
click_conversion.conversion_value = conversion_value
click_conversion.conversion_date_time = conversion_time
click_conversion.currency_code = currency_code

conversion_upload_service = self.adwords_client.get_service("ConversionUploadService")
request = self.adwords_client.get_type("UploadClickConversionsRequest")
request.customer_id = customer_id
request.conversions.append(click_conversion)
request.partial_failure = True
conversion_upload_response = (
    conversion_upload_service.upload_click_conversions(
        request=request,
    )
)
uploaded_click_conversion = conversion_upload_response.results[0]
print(
    f"Uploaded conversion that occurred at "
    f'"{uploaded_click_conversion.conversion_date_time}" from '
    f'Google Click ID "{uploaded_click_conversion.gclid}" '
    f'to "{uploaded_click_conversion.conversion_action}"'
)
```